# Do capacitors and inductors have initial voltage or current in small signal approximation problems?

Tags: capacitor, small-signal

I'm trying to solve a small signal approximation problem. The operating voltage for the capacitor is 2 volts. I simplified capacitor by a linear one. In solving this problem should I consider the **initial voltage** of the capacitor 2 volts or 0?

[image]

Comment: we'll need your full schematic and initial conditions to answer that.

Comment: What does "I simplified capacitor by a linear one" even mean?

Comment: @JYelton the q-v equation for the capacitor is "q=0.1v^3 + 0.8v" and the operating voltage was 2, so I replaced it with a linear one that its capacity is 2 F.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm looking for step response of capacitor's voltage.

Comment: This capacitor seems like it’s non linear according to that equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Okay, in this case I think you can either apply the full input voltage of 10V + 0.2u(t) and assume 2V as the initial capacitor voltage OR apply the input of 0.2u(t) with initial voltage of 0V and add the 2V back to the response afterward.

Comment: I'm looking for the step response. The small signal is 0.2u(t).

Comment: Are you doing a SPICE simulation or a manual calculation? Your input is actually 2V + 0.2u(t)?

Comment: Input is actually 10V + 0.2u(t), and it's a manual calculation.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I red the situation like this:

Input voltage V1 steps from 10 to 10.2 volts at t=0. V1=10 volts has been stayed constant before t=0, so V2 has initial value =2V. Cx is non-linear, it is given as "the charge q in Cx is as Ampere-seconds = (0.1u^3 + 0.8u) where number u is = V2 in volts". Wanted: I1 and V2 as functions of time.

The questioner tries to do the calculations by assuming dq/dt gives the valid linearized current for Cx and with it the Cx really as linearized to operating point V2=2V is 2 Farads. I agree. Cx=2F is the right linearized capacitance.

Some opinions: Cx is non-linear and replacing it with a linear capacitance is not at all mathematically acceptable way to get the small signal response. At least the replacement should be based on some non-linear circuit analysis theorem, not on assumptions catched from the wind.

This is catched from the wind: V2 rises so little that the effective capacitance Cx=2F is a reliable assumption for what Cx actually does.

How much V2 rises? My head is too ineffective to see it without calculations. The steady state final V2 is only 40 mV more than the initial value 2V, but what happens in the transient is the difficult part. One could say that the effective capacitance rises, so it even more reduces the swing of voltage V2. But as well he could say that L has more time to accumulate current, so there's more charge to be fed into Cx. Thus I have not a slightest idea does some transient oscillation exist and how high is the peak.

Some circuit analysis software allow voltage and current dependent parts in transient analysis. That shouldn't be no problem to be utilized in this case because the derivative of q (as the questioner has already calculated but not written) gives directly the dynamic capacitance for state variable equations in the program. Simply set Cx=(0.3(V2)^2+0.8) Farads where V2 is in volts.

One of such programs is old Micro-Cap which seems again to be available here http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm. There was an era when it could be reached only via Wayback Machine. It was developer's business for 40 years. One year ago he made it free. In transient analysis with it the state variables must have right initial values V2=2 volts and I1=1A. In Micro-Cap one has state variable editor for setting them.

The result:

[image]

Voltage V2 seems to rise towards 2.04V without oscillations and current I1 visits in 1.025 A, but decays to final value 1.02 A.

There's no voltage oscillations, so it's now well believable that fixed 2F for Cx could be used without substantial errors. A plot proves it:

[image]

The transient only caused by the 0.2V step could in this case as well be calculated with zero initial values because the superposition is valid in linear circuits.

I saw only afterwards that in this case 0.2V step isn't high enough to make the linearized fixed Cx response and the non-linear Cx response substantially different. It's out of the scope of this answer to find how the error caused by the linearization could be estimated without performing the full non-linear analysis for the reference.

Comment: How does taking derivative of q=0.1v^3 + 0.8v give capacitance? Wouldn’t that just be current.

Comment: q = f(v). I = dq/dt = (dq/dv)(dv/dt) That's the elementary rule for the derivative of combined function. For capacitor the most general current law is I=C(dv/dt). Thus (dq/dv) is the dynamic capacitance.

Comment: Ah ok. Wouldn’t it just be simpler to just use C=qV, then divide q  equation by V? I mean it gives same result anyway.

Comment: It's not the same. multiplier 3 is left out. dq/dv=0.3v^2 + 0.8

Comment: Oh right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your incremental or small signal model should only include the incremental quantities, 2V is the kind of like the "bias point" for your capacitor. Think in terms of changes, so you should choose the initial voltage of 0V with your small signal input.